# UIActivity Indicator not displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

Hey guys with some help from a previous question I think I have almost got this working.. 
code below

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //... all your previous charge.

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

    activity.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    activity.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [self.tableview addSubview:activity];

    [activity startAnimating];

    [activity performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}
```

but nothing appears.. the code is not generating any errors.. so just woundering if I am missing something.

Comment: You haven't set a frame for your activity view. You might want to, so that you can control the size and position of it.

Comment: ahh.. will have a read about that now.. first time I have an activity indicator :P Was looking at examples but was never quite sure if they related to my problem.

Comment: You added the UIActivityIndicatorView directly to a UITableView -- as a result it may be behind any table view cells (and thereby invisible).

Comment: yea I was wondering if that was the case.. so sounds like the frame is the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to try:

- it's not clear if your `tableView` is appearing and/or populated with data. set a non-white background color for the `tableView` if there is any doubt as to if the table is there. If you don't see the `tableView`, fix that first or add the `activityIndicatorView` as a subview of a different view you know you can see.
- set a frame for the `activityIndicatorView` so you know exactly where it's supposed to appear
- remove the `UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth` and `UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight` options from the `autoResizingMask` of the `activityIndicatorView`. You don't want the `activityIndicatorView` to change size based on it's superview.
- you are using a white activity indicator. make sure it will show up given the colors in your tableview and cells. unless you have a dark colored table, I find the gray activity indicator to be more visible.
- get rid of your timer to stop the animation, at least until you make sure you can see the `activityIndicatorView`. this is a wierd UX IMHO. generally you should start/stop the activity indicator based on a process in your app that you want users to be aware of
- likewise, set `hidesWhenStopped = NO` until you make sure you can see the `activityIndicatorView`.

When you can see the `activityIndicatorView` and everything looks good to your satisfaction you can add the behaviors back that you want.

Comment: okay cool. going to go over this stuff now. will let you know how I go.

Comment: okay I have done everything you have asked.. and it didnt work. However I think I might know why.. but not how to solve. Because my application is navigational based app where I load views into a navigationcontroller that I am setting up in my appdelegate. I have no idea how to get around this.

Comment: I had a feeling you had some other problems. You'll need to post more code showing how you initialize and present your root view controller. Also explain what is happening (e.g. do you think your nav controller and it's root view controller are being loaded and presented)?

Comment: I will try to explain this best I can. In my appdelegates.nib I have a UIView that holds the navigationcontroller view in that.. which I load all of my tableviews into etc. I'm guessing this is the problem but I do not know how to fix it\

Comment: I'm sure the problem is very simple but w/o more relevant code I don't know how to help.

Comment: :P I just am not sure what I need to show you :P lol what about a team view session? lol

Comment: One peice of code I can think of to show you is how I am initalising my activityindicator frame.. is this wrong or right.... 

activity = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray] initWithFrame:frame];

Comment: ok. my guess is that you have one or more of the following problems: 1) the outlets in your NIB file are not correctly configured in your app delegate and/or view controller. 2) the view controller and it's views are not properly configured. 3) the view controller that you reference above is not being presented. maybe something else similar. it's very likely just a config issue. you can test if code is being run in various places with NSLog() statements. I would do this in your `viewDidLoad` above for example.

Comment: I would also recommend taking a step back and looking at Apple's View Controller Programming Guide. There are good examples and you can make sure your code matches what needs to be done.  Good luck!

Comment: no, that is wrong for the activity indicator. set the frame with `activityView.frame = myFrame` after you have initialized the activityView.

Comment: guess what.. that worked.. son of a monkey! lol.. now I just need to learn how to put it in one of those dark boxes with text below it and dimmed backgroudn :P:P fingers crossed! thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have set it to be hidden when it stops animating and the perform selector stops the animation 0.5 seconds After starting the animation. In addition this is all being done during the view did load method.  You cannot guarantee that the view will be visible immediately after the view is loaded.  so it could be that the animation starts and stops before the view is even shown!

Try putting the perform selector in the viewDidAppear method and, at least initially, set the delay to a longer time.  You can always change the time back once you know it is visible.

Good Luck

Comment: I set the timer out to 20 seconds at one poin, that didn't work unfortunatly. so frustrating lol

Comment: But did you put the performSelector method in the viewDidAppear method?

Comment: no I put it in view didload, and it dosnt seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the **tableview cell** comes above the **indicator view**.Either you put your activity indicator in `tableView.tableHeaderView` or in `tableView.tableFooterView`.

**Or**

use `[self.view addSubview: activity];` to add indicator to the parent view rather than tableView.
Hope this will work..

Comment: thanks for the help but this didnt work. I think that maybe I am doing something critically wrong.